# Is kernel 3.16.0-60-generic valid?

Tags: kernel

When I perform a `sudo apt-cache search linux-image` I do not see the kernel version 3.16.0-60. Is this a valid kernel? My other Ubuntu workstations only have 3.16.0.49.

Answer (score 2):

It is an officially available version for 14.04. From [the package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic):

> #### Package linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic
>
> - [trusty (14.04LTS)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic) (kernel): Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP 
>     3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1 [**security**]: amd64 i386
> - [trusty-updates (kernel)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic): Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP 
>     3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1: amd64 i386

From [the changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-lts-utopic/linux-lts-utopic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1/changelog), it's from late January:

```
linux-lts-utopic (3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1) trusty; urgency=low

  [ Luis Henriques ]

  * Release Tracking Bug
    - LP: #1536149
  * Merged back Ubuntu-lts-3.16.0-58.78~14.04.1

 -- Luis Henriques <luis.henriques@canonical.com>  Wed, 20 Jan 2016 11:30:01 +0000
```